# DB2 renumbering Value from table based on given input

Tags: java, database, db2

I have scenario like, I have two columns

```
from   |    to
---------------
abc    |   pqr
pqr    |   xyz
```

`from` column value assigned with `to` column. I wanted to renumber the given input from the table. If I given `abc` then, it should return me `xyz`. Because `abc` assigned with `pqr` and `pqr` is assigned with `xyz`. so `xyz` is the renumbered value for `abc`. Like this if I give input, my query should check all assigned values and return last assigned value. How can I do that.

I have tried so far `select  tocolumn from table where fromcolumn='abc'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use Recursive Common Table Expression (RCTE):

```
WITH 
/*
  TAB (from, to) AS 
(
VALUES
  ('abc', 'pqr')
, ('pqr', 'xyz')
)
,
*/
T (LEVEL, FROM) AS 
(
SELECT 0, TO FROM TAB WHERE FROM='abc'
  UNION ALL
SELECT T.LEVEL+1, A.TO FROM TAB A, T WHERE A.FROM = T.FROM
)
SELECT FROM 
FROM T 
ORDER BY LEVEL DESC 
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```